# WooCommerce save customer earlier during the checkout

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

Good evening.

We have split up the checkout in the following steps:

1. Login / register
2. Customer information (checkout form)
3. Payment
4. Thank you page

We want to store the customer details / register the user after step 2, so that abandoned cart can pick up the information even before the client starts entering the payment info. Based on the customers billing country we want to show one of two options for step 3, strip or Klarna Checkout. If possible without refreshing the page.

So the question is, how can we register the user using jQuery Ajax (on click of the proceed to step 3 button)?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help you, a plugin called
Woocommerce Live Checkout Field Capture

capture details when customer is typing.

Sorry if my post doesn't help.